# Error while using PHP to call Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures

i am new to PHP, and am testing a simple PHP to call a Stored Procedure. I can connect to the Oracle database, but when i try to call oci_execute($stmt),
it will always failed. There is no issue with the stored procedure as it is being used by my other java program. Please advise what is the problem.
Thank.

```
$db="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=DEVORA)(PORT=1590)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=xxxORxxx)))";

$conn = oci_connect("xxxx","xxxx",$db);          

if (!$conn) {
   $m = oci_error();
   echo $m['message'], "\n";
   exit;
}
else {
   print "Connected to Oracle!\n";
}

$sql = 'BEGIN tcwzusr.getuserapp(:output_cur, :userid, :effdate); END;';

$stmt = oci_parse($conn,$sql);                     
$userid='myid01';
$effdate='01-12-2017';
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':userid'  ,$userid);           
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':effdate' ,$effdate);           

$output_cur = oci_new_cursor($conn);

oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':output_cur', $output_cur,-1, OCI_B_CURSOR);

oci_execute($stmt); 
if ( !$status ) {
    // Rollback the procedure
print "rollback\n";
    oci_rollback($conn);
    die ("$status_msg\n");
}
```